# Editting Music Files

Tags: audio-player

I have a bunch of music files. I will provide them through a website. I want to make the music files available only to a few music editing softwares. We have Vegas pro and avid in mind.

I would like to know if the following scenario is technologically feasible.

When the user clicks the download button, they receive a virtual file. If the user double clicks the virtual file, then the user downloads the original file. The physical file can only be inserted into pre-designated music editing software. The physical file cannot be moved to other directory besides the directory of the music editing software. This physical file should be destroyed after a certain amount of time.

Is this scenario possible?

Comment: "Is this scenario possible?" I sincerely hope not.

Comment: Sounds like a malicious virus scenario, no, it's not possible.